# Is there any benefit of executing "| xargs" without any arguments?

Tags: bash, xargs

I came across scripts where `| xargs` is executed without any arguments. I started removing such occurrences because scripts just work without them but wanted to verify that I'm not missing something. Perhaps xargs defaults to sanitising some characters, etc.

```
... | cut -d: -f2- | xargs
```

Is there any point of having the `| xargs` above? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without any arguments `xargs` will combine all lines in the output into a single line, and will remove extra spaces:

```bash
$ echo $'a   b\nb'
a   b
b

$ echo $'a   b\nb' | xargs
a b b
```

Note that this will only work if the input of xargs is smaller than the maximum size of the command buffer. See example below:

```
$ seq 100 | xargs | wc -l
1
$ seq 1000000 | xargs | wc -l
53
```

Comment: With default arguments, `xargs` may also unescape quotes.

Answer (score 1):

As per @user000001's answer, it's useful to "cleanup" whitespaces (including newlines) from stdin, into nicely one-line single-space separated values.

An interesting use-case arises when you need to "join" these values in a shell CLI (by `join` I mean adding a separator between all values), for example, you want to sum the size of all files in your current directory (similar to `du` somehow):

```shell
$ stat *|sed -n 's/^size//p'|xargs
5589886 11669381 4096 1743 2467 4096 22447289 1784723 27472 203 4096 525 4096 4096 4511158 268533 131068 150307 75658 12288 4096 4096 102762 4096 4096 4096 7296 5782043 4096 4096 779 14855386 895468 4096 4096 227

# replace each single whitespace from `xargs` by `+` and pipe it to `bc`
# to get the sum of all numbers
$ stat *|sed -n 's/^size//p'|xargs|sed 's/ /+/g'|bc -l
68374006
```

Answer (score 1):

This construct might seem useful to flatten the input with `echo` (which is called by xargs by default) but it has a few border cases depending on the content of stdin AND the implementation of `echo`:

1. it might trim leading/trailing/duplicate white spaces:

   ```bash
   printf '%s\n' '  a' 'b  b' 'c  ' | xargs
   ```

   ```
   a b b c
   ```
2. as @user000001 explained, when the input is too long, `echo` will be called multiple times, giving you multiple lines of output
3. `xargs` has it's own escaping rules; for example the presence of single/double quotes in the input might break the command:

   ```bash
   printf '%s\n' "I'll be there" | xargs
   ```

   ```
   xargs: unmatched single quote
   ```
4. `echo` has undefined behaviors; the output of

   ```bash
   printf '%s\n' 'a\\nb' | xargs    # \\ means \ for xargs
   ```

   could be

   ```
   a\nb
   ```

   as well as

   ```
   a
   b
   ```

---

###### ASIDE

For a sure-fire method of flattening the input, I would replace:

```bash
... | cut -d: -f2- | xargs
```

with:

```bash
... | cut -d: -f2- | paste -sd ' ' | sed 's/ \+/ /g; s/^ //; s/ $//'
```

<sup>**note:** the `sed` is for trimming leading/trailing/duplicate white spaces</sup>